# Why send messages from the superclass to get specialisations in the template method pattern?

Tags: ruby, inheritance, design-patterns

I've been reading Sandi Metz's book on OOP in Ruby. In the chapter on inheritance there is a section on the template method pattern.

It talks about having a base class with common behaviour, then subclasses that inherit this behaviour and implement their own specialised interfaces as needed.

The book goes on to discuss how to send messages from the base class to the subclass methods to get the specific behaviour and override defaults, like so:

```
class Bicycle
  attr_reader :size, :chain, :tire_size

  def initialize(**opts)
    @size = opts[:size]
    @chain = opts[:chain] || default_chain
    @tire_size = opts[:tire_size] || default_tire_size
  end

  def default_chain
    "11-speed"
  end

  def default_tire_size
    raise NotImplementedError
  end
end

class RoadBike < Bicycle
  def default_tire_size
    "23"
  end
end
```

What is the benefit of getting the base class to make this call to a method in a sub class, if the method can be defined in the subclass itself?

Comment: overriding defaults happens here `@tire_size = opts[:tire_size] || default_tire_size`. For example, `RoadBike.new.tire_size` returns the default `"23"` and to override it  `RoadBike.new(tire_size: "99").tire_size` returns `"99"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see why is this desirable we need to look at the previous iteration of the code (on p126 in my copy):

```rb
class Bicycle
  attr_reader :size, :chain, :tire_size

  def initialize(args={})
    @size      = args[:size]
    @chain     = args[:chain]     || default_chain
    @tire_size = args[:tire_size] || default_tire_size
  end

  def default_chain
    '10-speed'
  end
end
```

Spot the problem? There is an implicit and *undocumented* expectation that subclasses will implement `default_tire_size`. If they don't the code blows up in the constructor.

Sandi says on p128:

> Explicitly stating that subclasses are required to implement a message
> provides useful documentation for those who can be relied upon to read
> it and useful error messages for those who cannot.

The superclass `Bicycle` is an abstraction of the behavior common to all concrete subclasses. In this example the `default_tire_size` in `Bicycle`'s public interface tells interested parties (e.g. maintainers of `Bicycle` subclasses) that there is an expectation that a default tire size will be set. An exception is raised if the method is not implemented in a subclass. The exception is a clear pointer of what has gone wrong - you ain't implemented something you oughta. Much better than a potentially puzzling `undefined local variable or method 'default_tire_size'` no?